# Creating custom domain names for api

Tags: .htaccess, api, dns, cpanel, custom-domain

I have a web server using cpanel and I would like to use a custom domain on one folder for an api. So if I created a folder called api in the public_html folder then the path to that folder would be www.example.co.uk/api/(some php file). How could I change it so the folder would become a custom domain of api.example.co.uk/api/(some php file).

I have looked at a few options but don't really know the best way. I have tried to add a htaccsess file to the api folder and then create a rewrite rule to rewrite the www to api.

I also then looked at creating sub domains with the path to the api folder.

I have read that creating a A record on the server could work but I'm not quite sure how to do this. I know it can be done as most apis use some custom domain like facebooks graph api. (i.e https://graph.facebook.com/youtube/)

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on if you have access to make DNS records for your root domain, `example.co.uk`. For example right now `www.` is a `CNAME` or `A` record (depends on how your web server is set up), that resolves to the address of your web server. If you made an identical record but named it `api.` (`api. IN A ip-of-webserver`), then `api.example.co.uk` would do the same thing that `www.example.co.uk` does. This is kind of pointless if they go to the same web server though, the `/api/` part of the route makes it clear enough that the routes are for the api. What subdomains like facebook's are doing are pointing to a completely different application, and different web servers. For example, a company may have domains like `mail.company.com`, `portal.company.com`, `sso.company.com`, that all resolve to the address of different web servers for the different apps they have, but in this case it sounds like you are running one web server which is fine, you can have one web server be the api as well as serve the website.